# Как в inline mode отредактировать сообщение после нескольких секунд его отправки? aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Как после отправки item, сообщение редактировалось как в item_2? Ну или как можно по другому это реализовать (кроме callback кнопок)
Код:

````
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.types import InputTextMessageContent, InlineQueryResultArticle
import os, uuid
from time import sleep

bot = Bot(token="TOKEN")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Inline Mode
@dp.inline_handler()
async def inline_handler(query: types.InlineQuery):
    text = query.query or "None"

    item = InlineQueryResultArticle(
        id=str(uuid.uuid4()),
        title=f'Result {text!r}',
        input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
            message_text="test"))

    item_2 = InlineQueryResultArticle(
        id=str(uuid.uuid4()),
        title=f'Result {text!r}',
        input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(
            message_text="test2"))

    await bot.answer_inline_query(query.id, results=[item], cache_time=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dispatcher=dp,
                           skip_updates=True)```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
import uuid
from asyncio import sleep

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import ChosenInlineResult
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton as ib
from aiogram.types import (InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineQuery,
                           InlineQueryResultArticle, InputTextMessageContent)
from aiogram.utils import executor

bot = Bot(token="")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Inline Mode
@dp.inline_handler()
async def inline_handler(query: InlineQuery):
    text = query.query or "Введите текст."

    item = InlineQueryResultArticle(
        id=str(uuid.uuid4()),
        title=f"Result {text!r}",
        input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent(message_text=text),
        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(
            ib(text="-", callback_data="true")
        ),
    )

    await bot.answer_inline_query(query.id, results=[item], cache_time=0)


@dp.chosen_inline_handler()
async def chosen_inline_handler(result: ChosenInlineResult):
    await sleep(1)
    await bot.edit_message_text(
        "Пример Редактирования", inline_message_id=result.inline_message_id
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dispatcher=dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]